# Route parameters Laravel 4

Tags: parameters, routes, laravel

I've been trying to get this work but somehow its not working.

```
Route::get('account/edit/{id}', array('before' => 'auth', function($id)
{
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$provider = Provider::find($id); 

return View::make('provider.accountEdit')->with(compact('provider'));
}));
```

I'm trying to put the user ID on the url bit so like user/account/1

Comment: Can you give us the error, or describe how it's not working.

Comment: Its not saying any errors just when I go try edit a user linked to this <a href="account/edit" > it shows like route doesn't not exist yet or something.

Comment: Also if I remove the $id in function() and /{id} the page works fine

but I want to get the ID and shows on the url mysite.com/user/id

Comment: You are retrieving `$id` as a route parameter, but immediately replaces it with `Auth::user->id`. I really can't understand what you are trying to do here.

Even with that route function look legit and could you post the output of `php artisan routes` from root folder of the laravel installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the `id` optional so you can check if you are getting an `id` value.

Make `'account/edit/{id}` to `'account/edit/{id?}`

I think you are getting route doesn't exist error because the url doesn't match your route which have an id.

Comment: Yeah seems like the url doesn't match with the route, <a href="account/edit" > this is the link that's going to the edit page or calling the page. I tried {id?} didn't work.

Comment: Did you also change the `function($id)` to `function($id=null)`, if you have then you should browse `account/edit` with out error.

Answer (score 0):

Well I put the `Auth::user()->id` because in the `$provider = Provider::find($id)` it will say Unidentified variable id so I thought I'd put the Auth::user but sounds like thats wrong.
This bit is to fill the form in the edit page.

```
$provider = Provider::find($id); 
return View::make('provider.accountEdit')->with(compact('provider'));
```

This is what the php artisan routes says about the account/edit

```
URI                | Name | Action  |
GET /account/edit  |      | Closure | auth
```

Comment: Seems like your route has not been registered properly. When I use the same syntax, `php artisan routes` out put was
      |        | GET /account/edit/{id} |      | Closure | auth           |               |

Comment: Oh yes, I removed the {id} so it shows what i posted but even with edit/{id} its still not working :/. I ran php artisan routes again and result is GET /account/edit/{id} || Closure | auth.

So I tried account/edit/1 <- that works but when I click the edit button <a href="account/edit"> it doesn't work its not showing the id.

Comment: Shouldn't it be <a href="account/edit/1"> ? `account/edit` and `/account/edit/{id}` are different paths.

Comment: <a href="account/edit/1"> if I use this it will always say edit/1 not the actual if of certain user.

Comment: I used 1 as placeholder. You have to change the uri to include the id of "ceratin user". Like if you are using blade.

`<a href="account/edit/{{$user->id}}">`